# How to send continuation token to query azure time series insights?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I'm querying the database to retrieve time-series data using C# library DataPlaneClient (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-Time-Series-Insights/tree/master/csharp-tsi-preview-sample)  and I can't get more than 10,000 timestamps.

I've tried to see where exactly it should add the Continuation Token but failed to do so. I even used postman thinking that it might be a bug from the library itself.

The result is still 10,000 timestamp even though I expect more results or, at the least, some continuation token so I can keep querying for more data.

Answer (score 0):

The continuation token should be a *header* called x-ms-continuation with the value that you get from your initial query.